# How to separate Visualforce table by a value?

Tags: apex, visualforce, query, pageblocktable, table

I'm trying to separate my Visualforce table by Hummer's `Id` value:

```
public List<Hammer__c> getHummers() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Hammer__c];
}

public List<Factory__c> getFactories() {
    List<Hammer__c> hummers = getHummers();
    List<Factory__c> factories;

    for(Hammer__c h : hummers){
        factories = [SELECT Name FROM Factory__c WHERE Hammer__c =: h.Id];
    }
    return factories;
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!hummers}" var="h" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!h.Name}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!factories}" var="f" border="1px" width="100%">
                <apex:column value="{!f.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

But of caurse I get only the last Factory List (after `return factories`) with the same values:
[image]
How can I fix it to get values for each Hummer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the below code snippet:

Apex Class:

```
public List<Hammer__c> getHummers() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Factories__r ) FROM Hammer__c];
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!hummers}" var="hummer" >
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!hummer.Name}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!hummer.Factories__r}" var="factory" border="1px" width="100%">
            <apex:column value="{!factory.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

Let me know if this is something you are looking for.

**Note**: I assume you have the plural name as **Factories__r**.

Also, just wanted to add a comment on your code, Query or DML in the for Loop are not at all recommended and you will end up in hitting the Governer Limits of the salesforce in case you have one.

Comment: Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can make use of the `relationship queries`. You can query on `Factory__c` object along with the `Hammer__c` object which will tie the `factory` records to its respective `hammer` record.

That way, it would need only single query and only one method i.e. `getHummers` would suffice your needs and there won't be any need to use `maps` to associate `factory` records to `hummer` records.

You can read about [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) from Salesforce documentation or can go through the [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) trailhead module to know more on this topic.

So here is how you can use realtionship queries in your controller

```
public List<Hammer__c> getHummers() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Factories__r) FROM Hammer__c];
}
```

And your visualforce page name would be

```
<apex:repeat value="{!hummers}" var="h" >
        <apex:pageBlock title="{!h.Name}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!h.Factories__r}" var="f" border="1px" width="100%">
                <apex:column value="{!f.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Note : Assuming `Factories__r` as the child relationship name, if not, then replace the child relationship name with `Factories__r` in both controller and visualforce page.**

Comment: Thank you for help :)